# Power BI - limiter a filter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using a direct query connection in a database with millions of row. I need create a Table chart to allow users to download data to your local machine.
Are there a way to limit the user to filter just 7 days in a filter range?

Comment: Any 7 day range (not just the last 7 days)?

Comment: Any 7 days range in a Database with 2 years of range.I need that because more than 7 days will let the Database Server to slow to process these data, and the user wants to dowload to consume it in a XLSX file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a clean way to limit the data like that. As a workaround, you might consider trying to limit the date range within the measures.

```
DateLimitedMeasure =
VAR MaxDate = MAX ( DimDate[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Measure],
        FILTER ( DimDate, DimDate[Date] > MaxDate - 7 )
    )
```

For this measure, if the selected date range is more than 7 days, it returns a blank if it's not part of the last 7 days of that range.

Comment: I've created a measure like that, and I used it on filter tab.

filter control = if(([filter control max] - [filter control min])*1 > 7,"out_range","range")